# Проверка строки

Tags: php, строки, проверка

Как проверить есть ли в строке цифры в php?

Comment: Регулярным выражением `/\d+/`.

Comment: @iapetus Даже плюс не нужен.

Comment: `if (preg_match('/\d+/', $string)) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP. Есть ли в строке цифры?**

По условию задачи мы не знаем, что строка содержит, сколько в ней цифр и есть ли они вообще в ней. Поэтому самым подходящим способом будет использовать регулярные выражения.

Какое выражение использовать. Вариантов два: `/\d/` (или `/[0-9]/`, что тоже самое) и `/\d+/`. Первое выражение выберет один первый встретившийся числовой символ в строке, второе - первый встретившийся один или больше символов подряд. Если чисел не будет - ничего не выберет.

В комментарии даже код привели для задачи `if (preg_match('/\d+/', $string)) { ... }`

Функция вернет:

1. Если в строке нет цифр - `false`
2. Если есть - `true`. Указав третьим параметром функции массив, то получим в нем первое вхождение цифры (одной или больше подряд).

Потренировать скилл регулярных выражений можно на различных онлайн ресурсах. Мне нравится этот https://regex101.com/

А еще у PHP одна из самых лучших документаций ЯП. Причем на русском языке. http://php.net/manual/ru/index.php